# Intershop building url and access language property file from a pipeline

Tags: java, json, url, intershop

I am trying to create a JSON response but I need some things that is easily done in ISML. First I would like to know how I can build a proper URL this should link to a pipeline call with some parameters. The other thing I would like to know is how can I access language property files in a pipelet/java like the istext tag that you can call with ISML

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you do not like to use the URL with the pipeline name, you can create a short URL in the back office, or create a URL rewrite rule.
Every parameter you add to the URL will of course be available in the pipeline dictionary.
To get a localized text in Java take a look at the GetLocalizedTextByKey pipelet.
It uses the LocalizationProvider to provide a localized text for a specific key and a locale.
You can also take a look at this Intershop Knowledge Base article if you have access: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2258M5